# Should I use "in a" or "as a" in the following sentence?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

> I snickered, a snicker that ended **in** a sigh.
>
> I snickered, a snicker that ended **as** a sigh.

What's the correct option and why?

The second sentence has only [one](https://www.google.com.tw/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1ASUC_enTW628TW628&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22laugh%20*%20ended%20*%20a%20sigh%22) hit on Google. So, I'm a bit skeptic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no real difference in your two sentences they are both correct and understandable, it's only stylistic, they both have the same meaning.

> I snickered, a snicker that ended in a sigh.

means you sighed at then at the end, you sighed, the sigh may be considered separate from your snickering.

> I snickered, a snicker that ended as a sigh.

means your snickering *turned into* a sigh at the very end.

Comment: I would have said "in", because the sentence with "as" could be read as "I tried to snicker, but it ended up being a sigh". Or am I imagining things?

Comment: Well, the sentence explicitly says "a snicker that ended", which means you had already snickered, so it establishes you were successful snickering in the beginning.  If the sentence was "I snickered and it ended **up** as a sigh." it would mean what you are thinking.